# Why do characters in "That 70's Show" mention their parents by their names?

Tags: that-70s-show

In *That 70's Show* it is almost always seen that when Eric talks about his father he uses his father's first name "Red" and Donna uses "Bob and Midge" for her parents and I think Steven Hyde also does the same for his mother. 
I personally find that disrespectful and unusual in general.

Is it a common practice in US culture?

But I have seen other American movies and TV shows where people refer to parents by Daddy, Mom, Pappa etc (e.g. *Friends*).

So is this something specific to the 1970s?

Comment: It's not *uncommon* but it is situational dependent. It's a cultural thing.

Comment: It is sometimes a "thing" for rebellious teenagers to do.

Comment: Compare *The Simpsons* where Bart always refers to Homer by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some cases it does not always mean disrespect, as some parents may encourage or allow this in order to provide trust and create more equal footing by attempting an anti-authoritarian approach to parenting.

However, in the case of *That 70's Show* it most likley is meant to invoke disrespect or a breakdown of previous American family structure, because the 1970's period is about the decline of a movement of young people ([hippies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippie) and [flower children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_child)) **rebelling against the establishment**, which is furthered by the backdrop of The Vietnam War.

> An [Anit-establishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-establishment) view or belief is one which stands in opposition
>   to the conventional social, political, and economic principles of a
>   society. The term was first used in the modern sense in 1958, by the
>   British magazine New Statesman to refer to its political and social
>   agenda. Antiestablishmentarianism (or anti-establishmentarianism)
>   is an expression for such a political philosophy.

In some ways *That 70's Show* sometimes mocks "Hippie culture", because like in real life, it became a part of mainstream culture, becoming marketable, proving the lack of organization from the 1960's birth (Summer of Love) a failed venture, but still pushed for other sociopolitical movements, such as the sexual revolution.

One way to rebel against the establishment would be to break the social norms between parents and children. However I do not recall if this was true in each case of every character that did so on the TV series and of course there is loads of irony coming from all directions of political correctness of such a debate.

Comment: Is your use of the words “equivocate” and “wane” what you really mean here?

Comment: Ah cool, just checking.

Comment: "a part" and "apart" mean opposite things. Which do you mean?

Comment: Also note that in the case of Eric, he jumps between "my dad" and "Red" depending on the context. More often than not, "Red" is used when Eric thinks his dad is being Red, whereas "my dad" is used when Eric considers his dad to be acting like a normal dad.

Comment: Also note that it's not inherently 70's culture that ties into this. The Simpsons made it a key point that Bart calls Homer "Homer" ever since he can speak, much to Homer's discontent. This is part of Bart's rebellious nature. Lisa later does the same (as she is similarly rebellious, albeit in a different way), whereas Maggie is the first to call Homer "daddy".

Comment: Also, I don't think this is particularly done as a way to stick it to the man in general, but rather these particular characters having a bad relationship with their parents. According to the kids, Hyde's mom is neglectful, Donna's parents are idiots, Red is an asshole. All three have a personal reason to distance themselves from their parents. Kelso and Jackie have relatively good connections with their parents and subsequently don't call the by their first name.

Answer (score -2):

I believe they do it to add a sense of adulting and rebellion to the character's personalities.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this, or is it just a guess?

Comment: I do believe the core of your answer is correct, but the answer suffers from massive quality issues. A few tips to get you started (1) Elaborate your answer to explain your belief, rather than merely stating your belief and expecting us to put blind trust in your unfounded asumption (2) Can you corroborate your claim with examples from the show? (3) Can you compare why Hyde/Donna/Eric (who call their parents on a first name basis) are different from Jackie/Kelso (who don't?). These are good additions that dramatically improve the question.